# $p$ is a positive integer and $(p)$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $(\mathbb Z, +,\cdot)$, then $p$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integer-rings

I need to prove: $p$ is a positive integer and $(p)$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $(\mathbb Z, +,\cdot)$, then $p$ is a prime number.

My attempt:

1) $(p)$ is a maximal ideal, so it is a prime ideal.

2) Assume $p$ is not prime, then $p = ab, a,b \in \mathbb Z, a>0, b>0,a \ne 1,p$.

3) Because $(p)$ is a prime ideal, it means that either $b=z_1p$ or $a=z_2p, z_1>0,z_2>0, z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb Z$.

4) Assume that $b=z_1p$, then $1=az_1$ so $a= 1, z_1 =1$.

5) Assume that $a=z_2p$, then $1=bz_2$, so $b= 1, z_1 =1$, but then $a=p$.

Thus $p$ must be prime.

Is it a correct proof?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the contrapositive to be the clearest approach:

> If $p$ is not prime, then $(p)$ is not maximal.

Indeed, if $p$ is not prime, then $p$ has a proper divisor $a$ with $1 < a < p$.

But then $ \mathbb Z=(1) \supset (a) \supset (p)$, where all inclusions are strict, and $(p)$ is not a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle p \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $(\Bbb Z,+,\cdot)$.

Then we have that $ab\in \langle p \rangle \implies a\in \langle p \rangle$ or $b\in \langle p \rangle$

If $p$ is not prime, then take its prime factors $p=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ and clearly $$p=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}\in \langle p \rangle$$
$$\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}: p_i^{\alpha_i}\not\in\langle p\rangle\quad \text{ (maximal) }$$

Hence $\langle p \rangle$ is not prime(also these would generate a larger ideal), contradiction, hence $p$ is prime.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}: p_i^{\alpha_i}\not\in\langle p\rangle\quad$

Comment: @SergeyZykov If $p_i^{\alpha_i}\in \langle p \rangle$ then $\langle p \rangle$ is  non-maximal. (If $\langle p_i^{\alpha_i}\rangle = (\Bbb Z,+,\cdot)$, then $p_{i}^{\alpha_i}$ is a unit, and is not prime, so it generates an ideal(which is larger than our maximal ideal)).

Comment: Sorry not getting your reasoning here. If you claim that if $p_i^{\alpha_i}\in\langle p\rangle$, then $\langle p\rangle$ is not maximal, then you need to show that there is an ideal $\mathcal I: \langle p\rangle \subset \mathcal I \subset \mathbb Z$ where all inclusions are strict.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a nonprime number, thus $p$ can be factored in to two non-unit coprime  numbers, say $x$ and $y$ ($p = xy$, $\gcd(x, y) = 1$). Since $x$ and $y$ are non-units, so $\langle p \rangle \subset \langle x \rangle \neq \textbf{Z}$ and $\langle p \rangle \subset \langle y \rangle \neq \textbf{Z}$ (if $\langle p \rangle = \langle x \rangle$, then $x = nxy$, so $y$ is a unit). This shows that $\langle p \rangle$ is not maximal ideal.

Comment: are you sure about $p=xy, \gcd(x,y)=1$? How would you factor then $125=5*5*5$ into $x$ and $y$ such that $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed yourself ideal $\left(p\right)$ is also a prime ideal.

So $nm\in\left(p\right)\implies n\in\left(p\right)\vee m\in\left(p\right)$,
or equivalently $p\mid nm\implies p\mid n\vee p\mid m$.

This combined with $p\notin\{0,1,-1\}$ makes us say that $p$ is a so called
*prime element* of $\mathbb{Z}$.

This combined with the positivity of $p$ makes us say that $p$ is a *prime number*.

---

**edit**:

Every prime element is an irreducible element. Proof:

Let $p$ be a prime element and let $p=ab$.

Then $p\mid a\vee p\mid b$. If $p\mid a$ then $a=rp$ for some $r$.

Then $p=ab$ leads to $p(1-rb)=0$ and consequently $rb=1$ showing that $b$ is a unit.

Of course $p\mid b$ will lead to the conclusion that $a$ is a unit.

---

Applied to $\mathbb Z$ this shows that a prime number can be described as a positive integer that has exactly $2$ positive divisors: $1$ and itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think in it you take as obvious exactly the things I find (at my level) worth discussing. E.g. if $p$ is a positive prime element, then I am not sure why it should be a prime number (i.e. to satisfy the definition of prime numbers.

Comment: What is your definition of prime numbers? Is it like this: a positive integer that is divisible by exactly $2$ positive integers ($1$ and itself)? Then I understand your difficulty. Almost always that's the way a prime number is defined, but actually it is the definition of an *irreducible* positive number. In $\mathbb Z$ and also more rings, these concepts coincide.

Comment: $b$ can also be $-1$, so we conclude that either $b= \pm 1$ and then $a = \pm p$ or $a= \pm 1$ and then $b = \pm p$, so the only positive divisors of $p$ are $1,p$, thus $p$ is prime according to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Answer (score 0):

Let my try to elaborate answering this.

Assume $I=\langle p \rangle$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z$ for some prime $p$. Let $J$ be an ideal of $\Bbb Z$ with $I\subseteq J$. Since $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, $J=\langle a \rangle$ for some $a\in \Bbb Z$. Thus, $\langle p \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle$. If $\langle p \rangle \subsetneq \langle a \rangle$, then $a\notin \langle p \rangle$ (since otherwise $\langle a \rangle\subseteq \langle p \rangle$). So $p\nmid a$ and hence $\gcd(p,a)=1$. So, $1=sp+ta$ for some $s,t\in \Bbb Z$. Since $p\in \langle a \rangle$, is is $1\in \langle a \rangle$ and therefore $\langle a \rangle = \Bbb Z$. Hence $I$ is maximal.

Conversely, let $I=\langle a \rangle$ be a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z$, so $a\neq \pm 1$. Also, $a\neq 0$, since $\{0\}\subsetneq \langle z \rangle \subsetneq \Bbb Z$ for all $z\in \Bbb Z\setminus\{0,\pm1\}$. If $a$ is not a prime number, then $a=xy$ for some non-zero integers $x,y\neq \pm 1,\pm a$. Thus, $\langle a \rangle \subsetneq \langle x \rangle,\langle y \rangle \subsetneq \Bbb Z$, contradiction by the maximality of the ideal. So, $a$ must be prime.

---

Alternative way: Let $n > 1$. We have $\langle n \rangle \neq \Bbb Z$ is maximal iff $\Bbb Z/\langle n \rangle=\Bbb Z_n$ is a field iff $n$ is a prime number.